# Cordova android app crashes on Galaxy S3 ?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, galaxy-nexus, cordova-3.5

I am creating new android app using cordova. My app was crashed on **Galaxy S3** device. If i click link button on home page, it will crashed. Here i added the issue details. How to solve this issue. Please guide me.

I am using cordova version is 3.6.4.

```
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/d2tmo/d2tmo:4.3/JSS15J/T999UVUENC2:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '16'
    pid: 18307, tid: 18320, name: WebViewCoreThre >>> com.rcs.rcs <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
    Abort message: '@@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large'
    r0 00000027 r1 00000000 r2 00000008 r3 deadbaad
    r4 00000000 r5 5e8c0754 r6 5f752340 r7 5f752340
    r8 417dc000 r9 00000001 sl 000020ef fp 5e8c0c84
    ip 00000001 sp 5e8c0750 lr 400e4497 pc 400e19b8 cpsr 60000030
    d0 524f424120404040 d1 6568203a474e4954
    d2 7572726f63207061 d3 6564206e6f697470
    d4 4061db6db7281fda d5 000002d044870000
    d6 4434000044340000 d7 4499c000000004ce
    d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
    d18 bf847ae147ae147b d19 0000000500000009
    d20 0000000100000001 d21 0000000000000000
    d22 42ea000042ea0000 d23 41500000441c8000
    d24 0000381f0000381f d25 00003aed00003b86
    d26 3a3b38383a3b3d39 d27 262928282a2b2c26
    d28 1b1d19191b1a1b16 d29 ffffffffffffffff
    d30 00008800ffff4d00 d31 e92d4000ffff1d80
    scr 60000013

    backtrace:
    #00 pc 0001e9b8 /system/lib/libc.so
    #01 pc 0001c914 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #02 pc 00012495 /system/lib/libc.so
    #03 pc 0000ebb9 /system/lib/libc.so
    #04 pc 0000fa87 /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+606)
    #05 pc 0000dc53 /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
    #06 pc 0000091b /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new(unsigned int)+2)
    #07 pc 00291b79 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #08 pc 00291c41 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #09 pc 00291c79 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #10 pc 00020b4c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #11 pc 000516ab /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
    #12 pc 00029fe0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #13 pc 0002e9a4 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #14 pc 0006382d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
    #15 pc 00063857 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
    #16 pc 000585bb /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #17 pc 0000cc60 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #18 pc 0000cddc /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)

    code around pc:
    400e1998 461ce00b 2b006823 e026d1fb b12468e4 
    400e19a8 21014a18 6011447a 4b1247a0 24002027 
    400e19b8 f7fc7018 2106edcc e832f7fe 5180f04f 
    400e19c8 a9029104 94022006 9403460a ebcef7fd 
    400e19d8 46224629 f7fd2002 f7fcebda 2106edb8 
    400e19e8 e81ef7fe f7fc2001 6960ea64 d1dc2800 
    400e19f8 bf00e7d4 deadbaad 00029660 ffffff9c 
    400e1a08 0002c904 0002c8e8 2400b510 aa04b088 
    400e1a18 46699002 94014620 94039400 eb1cf7fd 
    400e1a28 db0642a0 b1139b07 1c419806 98069106 
    400e1a38 4620e000 bd10b008 4b1eb40e b082b5f0 
    400e1a48 447b491d f107af00 585e021c f8522101 
    400e1a58 68354b04 f852607d 31015b04 d1fa2d00 
    400e1a68 320e008a 0507f022 0220f107 0d05ebad 
    400e1a78 f107603a 46690224 9400466d 4c04f852 
    400e1a88 f8453204 2c004f04 f8dfd1f8 f853c030 

    code around lr:
    400e4474 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 260041f0 4680589c 
    400e4484 686768a5 f9b5e007 2b00300c 4628dd02 
    400e4494 430647c0 3f013554 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00 
    400e44a4 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00026b5c ffffffc4 
    400e44b4 43f0e92d fb01461e 4b16f502 4916460f 
    400e44c4 447bb087 aa014614 20019001 95029203 
    400e44d4 90049505 681a585b b1124698 f0094630 
    400e44e4 4630fd4a f7ffa903 4681fe9c 0000f8d8 
    400e44f4 4630b110 fd4cf009 0f00f1b9 9c05d005 
    400e4504 1b284639 ec4ef017 46204604 e8bdb007 
    400e4514 bf0083f0 00026b0e ffffff60 46036842 
    400e4524 60411e51 da012900 bbbcf000 f8126802 
    400e4534 601a0b01 00004770 4a104b0f b570447b 
    400e4544 589b4604 461e6819 f009b109 6860fd14 
    400e4554 60651e45 da042d00 f0004620 4605fba3 
    400e4564 6822e003 5b01f812 68336022 4620b113
```

Comment: share your code also...are you using jquery-mobile or any other SDK?

Comment: I am using basic html, css and jQuery. Not a jQuery mobile. While i am going to other pages only getting app crash.